# Register Python App with Spring Cloud Data Flow

Tags: python, spring-cloud-stream, spring-cloud-dataflow

I need to make use of python code libraries to do some NLP and ML. However, I also would like to use Spring Cloud Data Flow to register these python script apps etc.

I am using kafka as the messaging middleware for spring cloud stream. Ideally, I can code the business login in java and package them as a jar. However, I need python gensim to get NLP results back.

Is there any way I can solve this problem? Thanks

Answer (score 1):

We have a fleet of deployment options to run Python workloads in SCDF. There's, in fact, a recipe for each of the [deployment options in the Microsite](https://dataflow.spring.io/docs/recipes/polyglot/).

Feel free to try out the desired option and let us know if you have any feedback through issues in the [Microsite repo](https://github.com/spring-io/dataflow.spring.io).